# BoxLayout sticking to top

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, boxlayout

I just started messing around with the BoxLayout manager.

I've made two buttons next to each other, and the third one should go to the next line (underneath the first two), and the two first buttons should be at the top of the frame.

How can I accomplish this?

This is my current code

```
    Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    box.add(new JButton("Button"));
    box.add(new JButton("Hello"));


    box.add(Box.createVerticalBox());
    box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
    box.add(new JButton("Button2"));

    add(box);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks nothing like the description you give of what you want. It sounds like you need

- a top-level vertical box

  - a horizontal box

    - button
    - gap
    - button
  - gap
  - button

So something like

```
Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();

Box hbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
hbox.add(new JButton("Button"));
hbox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
hbox.add(new JButton("Hello"));
vbox.add(hbox);

vbox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
vbox.add(new JButton("Button2"));
```